# Open modal onclick button when it is produced by PHP echo

Tags: php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I need your help here please.I have a button which is echoed by a `PHP` file to a `HTML` file.When the button is clicked then I want a modal to be displayed in the `HTML` file.Does anyone have any idea how I can make this work?

PHP echo:

```
'<div class="modal fade" id="modelWindow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">'. $row['title'] .'</h4>
            </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="img-rounded" src="'. $row['image'] .'" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
       <p class="well">'. $row['description'] .'<p>

        </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>

           <div class="row top-buffer">
           <div class="col-md-6">
     <img class="img-rounded" src="'. $row['image'] .'" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
       <h3>'. $row['title'] .'</h3>
       <p class="well">'. $row['description'] .'<p>

       <div class="row top-buffer">

      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
      <img src="img/link_icon.png" class="img-rounded" width="20px" height="20px"/>
  <a href="www.link.com">LINK</a>
               </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">

  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btn">More...</button>
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>'
```

The first part is the modal box and the second is the HTML output

Script to triggger the modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#modelWindow").modal("show");
    });

</script>
```

Do I need to add the script to a external file and call it inside php or there is another way to do this?Thanks

Comment: `Do I need to add the script to a external file and call it inside php or there is another way to do this` both ways will work, but your modal classes should already be loaded.

Comment: I didn't include anything in the php file.You think that is the problem?

Comment: The lib which supports modal is already loaded before you php code echo's ?

Comment: No..So I must included them in the `head`?

Comment: yes offcourse, you need to load the libs first

Comment: I disagree. Don't include the libraries in the `<head>`. That slows down the page load because the browser won't show the page until everything in `<head>` is downloaded and parsed. External scripts should not block your page load if possible. Only put script in the head that is required for your page to display.  Look instead at the 2nd part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can include the script in the php echo just make sure that all dependencies like `jQuery` and `Bootstrap.js` is included on the page that will render the echoed data.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code cannot be triggered by PHP directly because PHP is run on the server, and Javascript is run in the client (eg the browser).  So what we need is a way to tell the browser to execute the code.

What you can do though is include the `<script>` in the string you're building in PHP

```
'<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#modelWindow").modal("show");
    });
</script>'
```

If jQuery and Bootstrap's Javascript have already been loaded when this is inserted into the DOM, the button click will work. If that doesn't work for you, try altering it to:

```
'<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){
      $("#btn").click(function() {
          $("#modelWindow").modal("show");
          });
   }
</script>'
```

Putting the code in `window.onload` guarantees that the browser will run it only after all external scripts are loaded. From the [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

Comment: I should `echo` this  `<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){
      $("#btn").click(function() {
          $("#modelWindow").modal("show");
          });
   }
</script>`??

Comment: Yes or place it directly in the HTML file.

Comment: I tried both solutions but it didn't work..Any idea why?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle example?

Comment: Did the javascript show up in the DOM? (open browser dev tools and look at where the PHP string is inserted). If you know how to fiddle a PHP script (I didn't know that was possible), provide a fiddle and I'll give you feedback.

Comment: Yes you are right.You can run `PHP` in fiddle.I will check this and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to trigger a modal if what you want to do is open a modal on an onclick even you can use something like this

`echo '<button onclick="$('#showmymodal').modal('show')">click to open modal</button>';`

if you want to do it on a php function use this and it will automatically trigger the modal when it is called!

```
echo "<script>$('#showmymodalnow').modal('show')</script>";
```

I personally like using the onclick event straight from HTML like this

```
<button onclick="$('#showmymodal').modal('show')">click to open modal</button>
```

I hope this helps someone